# Generic Payload for Prism Event Aggregator

Tags: c#, generics, prism, eventaggregator

I am developing an WPF application and tried to design something event driven using Prism's Event Aggregator.

Currently I am trying to implement something like event queue for Prism events.
To do that I want to subscribe related events and pass them to same method but Event Aggregator wants those methods to have same signature with the event.

Example events:

```
public class TestEvent1 : PubSubEvent<Class1>
{
}
public class TestEvent2 : PubSubEvent<Class2>
{
}
public class TestEvent3 : PubSubEvent<List<Class3>>
{
}
public class TestEvent3 : PubSubEvent<string>
{
}
```

Subscriptions:

```
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<TestEvent1>().Subscribe(OnTestEvent1, true);
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<TestEvent2>().Subscribe(OnTestEvent2, true);
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<TestEvent3>().Subscribe(OnTestEvent3, true);
```

Example callback method:

```
    private void OnTestEvent1(Class1 object1)
    {
        // do something      
    }
```

Since I only receive data when event published, I tried something like this to use as event payload type, but it doesn't look right:

```
// Payload
public interface IMessage
{
    public object Data { get; set; }
    public Type Datatype { get; set; }
    public PubSubEvent EventType { get; set; }
}

// Events
public class TestEvent1 : PubSubEvent<IMessage>
{
}
public class TestEvent2 : PubSubEvent<IMessage>
{
}
public class TestEvent3 : PubSubEvent<IMessage>
{
}

// Subscriptions
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<TestEvent1>().Subscribe(EventHandler, true);
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<TestEvent2>().Subscribe(EventHandler, true); 
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<TestEvent3>().Subscribe(EventHandler, true);

// Callback
private void EventHandler(IMessage payload)
{
    // do something      
}
```

Is this viable and how can I improve or change my "generic" payload?

Extra information:
In my scenario I have multiple UDP servers that periodically receives new data, deserialize it to objects and publish events.
Related "managers" subscribed to those events and get triggered when new data received.

My goal is try to implement an event queue like system in my event receiving classes so it will be easier to deal with multithreading issues.

Here are some diagrams that may help me explain myself better:

My architecture:

[image]

My "event queue"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a code-review question, isn't it?

I would very much prefer strong typing, though, and I wouldn't want to build a queue *around* the event aggregator, that will always be tedious because you never know when new event types show up. Instead, I'd build my own event aggregator with queueing built in (starting from the existing one).

Also, I'd look into dataflow, for example, because the basic working mode of the event aggregator (fire and forget, one sender, multiple or no receivers) doesn't seem to work well with queueing. If you queue at the sender-side, to you wait for one receiver or all? Do you queue when there are no receivers or do you discard then? If you queue at the receiver-side, why bother at all? The receiver can implement the queue on its own.

Comment: You are right about the code review questions but I think they want fully working solutions that works so I posted here, sorry. My goal is to create something like event queue on receiver ends. Only thing that the event handler will do is try to add the new received event to queue and return, then my worker part will periodically read the queue and call methods according to event types. Event publisher won't care about the results and missing some events because queue is full is not a problem since I receive my data periodically. I will add my my queue diagram to question, maybe it will help.

Comment: @Cagurtay just use a producer-consumer-queue that you like (`BlockingCollection`, `BufferBlock`, `AsyncProducerConsumerQueue` or `AsyncCollection` come to mind) on the subscriber side in your `Manager`.

Comment: @Cagurtay also, most likely, the `UDPService` can distribute the messages to the `Manager`s directly, using the event aggregator only for distributing to a (potentially unknown) set of view models. I strongly recommend looking into dataflow here which is specifically designed for data processing graphs like yours.

Comment: yep, I was thinking similar concurrent data structures but I want to write my received event type and data to same concurrent queue, so that's why I am trying to write an IMessage, IPayload like generic general type that I can use on all of my events. Otherwise don't I need to create different queue for every event?

Comment: I think each manager should have its own queue, in fact, I don't see a reason why they should share a queue.

Comment: Yes, each manager will have its own queue, but when I subscribe to an event from a receiving class, I have to assign a method for when event is published and that method must have same signature as the  event. So I can't create a catch all method for all of my events in that receiving class. ex: event: TestEvent1 : PubSubEvent<List<string>>, subscription: GetEvent<TestEvent1>().Subscribe(EventHandler, true); method: EventHandler(List<string> data). Because of this, if I want to queue all of the receiving events on the class I have to create different queues.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish an event with a reference to an object, consider these potential problems:

- Any listener will be dependent on the type/assembly of the event parameter.
- The referenced object will be held for some time. For how long? You don't know.
- The referenced object could have been altered/disposed.
- Listeners might handle the referenced object on a different thread.

After dealing with `PubSubEvent<T>` for several years now, I believe there is only one suitable pattern that successfully handles all cases. Publish your event with a unique identifier, e.g. a `Guid`.

```cs
public class MyItemAddedEvent : PubSubEvent<Guid> {}
```

Then inject a provider wherever you listen for this event:

```cs
public class SomeListener
{
    private readonly IMyItemProvider myItemProvider;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public SomeListener(IEventAggregator eventAggregator,
                        IMyItemProvider myItemProvider)
    {
        this.myItemProvider = myItemProvider;

        eventAggregator.GetEvent<MyItemAddedEvent>().Subscribe(OnMyItemAdded, true);
    }

    private void OnMyItemAdded(Guid id)
    {
        var myItem = myItemProvider.Get(id);
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Now it is the responsibility of the provider class to deliver a valid and up-to-date object given a unique id.

Comment: In my scenario publisher doesn't care if its events are proccessed or not since it receives data periodically. My goal is to process subscribed events sequantially, without any multithreading issues on receivers ends. I will add my "event queue" diagram, maybe it will help to clarify my question.